# Using AngularJS for two-way binding of XML display to form fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Have a requirement where the user should be able to display and update an XML using form fields.

To be able to display the XML and bind the XML elements to from fields, I did the following:

1. Retrieve XML, convert to JSON (using xml2json) and put it in scope (name='domObject').
2. Use angular directive on the HTML to get the domObject from scope and beatify it and display it (using vkbeautify)
3. Also, on the same html, bind the form fields to the domObject from scope.

The binding from the domObject to the XML & form fields is working fine. But, when I make update the value in the field, the same is NOT reflected in the XML displayed (although the changes can be seen in the domObject) i.e 2 way binding is not happening when using the directive.

Please help.

Link to plunker **[here](https://plnkr.co/edit/zKyiBf3Vi1Oiy9Fd5XjQ?p=preview)**

### **Code Snippets**

Main script:

```
var App = angular.module('myApp', []);
App.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window) {

    $http.get("sample.xml")
        .then(function(response) {

        var x2js = new $window.X2JS();
        var jsonDocument = x2js.xml_str2json( response.data );
        $scope.domObject = jsonDocument;
        $scope.dataLoaded = true;
    });

})

App.directive('prettyprint', function($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        replace: true,
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            var x2js = new $window.X2JS();
            var xmlString = x2js.json2xml_str(scope.domObject);
            element.text(vkbeautify.xml(xmlString, 4));
        }
    };
});
```

HTML Snippet:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <section class="container">
                <div class="form-style-3" ng-controller="myCtrl">
                    <form novalidate ng-if="dataLoaded">
                        <fieldset><legend>Fields</legend>
                            Catalog Name
                            <input type="text" ng-model="domObject.catalog.name" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
              <br />
          <div>
            <br />
                    XML Display:
                    <pre class="prettyprint lang-xml" ng-if="dataLoaded"></pre>

                    DOM Object: <br /><br />
                    {{domObject}}

                </div>
                </div>

    </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `prettyprint` directive takes `scope.domObject` initially and doesn't reflect to its changes.

One of the ways to do this is to setup a [watcher](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) like:

```js
App.directive('prettyprint', function($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
          obj: '='
        },
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('obj', function(val) {
              var x2js = new $window.X2JS();
              var xmlString = x2js.json2xml_str(val);
              element.text(vkbeautify.xml(xmlString, 4));
            }, true)
        }
    };
});
```

Here is [working plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/QSSzcgZRthiWohXHKgyh?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for the super quick response Stan. Works like a charm. Can't thank you enough. I tried with 'watch' on the 'domObject' directly from scope, but that obviously didn't work.